# How can i call a function on a base component from a dialog window in Angular

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to call a function on a component. Here is my Setup, i have a reusable component which is my base for all data displayed in grids and includes the filter logic, chips for filters, export and the actual grid. All that works great so far. Now i have instances where user can click on a row and edit some data which is displayed in a dialog window via angular material. ll that is working fine but what i am trying to do is to go and reload the grid after a user made changes or added data.
My Base component has a function called onGridRelaod

```
 onGridReload($event: IGridReloadPayload) {
        this.setDataFetcherFactory($event.currentDataFetcherParams);
        this.agGridBase.setDataSource(() => {
        });
    }
```

So the question is how can i call the onGridRelaod from my dialog ? I would assume i would have to expose it to the component which uses the base component and then have the dialog call it on the component which opened it. But not 100 % sure how to go about it

Comment: the dialog should not call it. Instead, it should signal when it has done its job (by resolving a promise or emitting from an observable: it would help if you told us which library you use for dialogs), and the caller, which opened the dialog, should then reload the grid.

Comment: I am using Material Dialog / mat-dialog to display my Edit Window when user clicks on the edit grid. One thing i dont want to is reload if there was no changes to the data made

Comment: Read https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview. It explains that the caller can subscribe to `dialogRef.afterClosed()` to know when the dialog is closed, and the component in the dialog can call MatDialogRef.close(someData) to close the dialog and emit an event.

Answer (score 1):

Try to emit the event from child component to parent.

Dialog component:

```
...
onAdd = new EventEmitter();

onButtonClick() {
  this.onAdd.emit();
}
...
```

Parent Component:

```
...
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component);
const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onAdd.subscribe(() => {
  // do something
});
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
  // unsubscribe onAdd
});
...
```

Comment: Ok, i am getting a bit closer, i am able to emit the reload from my dialog and the parent which opened it gets the emit. But that only gets me half way there as i need to be able to now call the reload on the component that is implemented. Detail hierarchic is in question

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your page structure but you can create sibling service that provide a signal Observable. Your modal push inside this observable to notify "something change". And your component can subscribe to it for reloading grid.

You can pass information like rowId for partial reload to speed up your reload.

the service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyTableService {
  public change: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

your modal

```
...
public onClose() {
  this.myTableService.change.next();
}
...
```

your component

```
...
public ngOnInit() {
  this.myTableService.change.subscribe(() => {
    this.onGridReload(...)
  })
}
...
```